# OpenCV - Fitting leaves inside the contour of fitEllipse()

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, shapes, image-recognition

In this project, i have to fit many different leaf images (one at a time) inside the ellipse to get the following informations:

1)Aspect Ratio;

2)Mean Diameter, measuring the diameter for each 2 degrees;

3)Radius ratio;

4)Roundness;

5)Mean Feret.

The problem is: when i try to fit the object inside the ellipse, the ellipse is actually drawn inside it, and because of that, the height and width of the object are wrong.
I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong, since I'm using findNonZero() to get only parts of the image that actually has pixels.

Here is the result: [image]

Here is my code:

```
/*Load the image*/
Mat img_bgr = imread("image path", 1);
if (img_bgr.empty()){
    cout << "No image found..." << endl;
    return -1;
}

/*Display the image*/
namedWindow("Original Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Original Image", img_bgr);
waitKey(0);

/*Conversion to HSV*/
Mat img_hsv;
cvtColor(img_bgr, img_hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

/*Extracting colors - HSV*/
Mat yellow, green, brown;

//Yellow
inRange(img_hsv, Scalar(25, 80, 80), Scalar(36, 255, 255), yellow);

//Green
inRange(img_hsv, Scalar(37, 80, 80), Scalar(70, 255, 255), green);

//Brown
inRange(img_hsv, Scalar(10, 80, 80), Scalar(30, 200, 200), brown);


/*Finding Contours of the Thresholded images*/
vector<std::vector<Point>>green_cnt;
vector<std::vector<Point>>yellow_cnt;
vector<std::vector<Point>>brown_cnt;

//Green Contour
findContours(green, green_cnt, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

//Draw the Contours - Green
Mat green_cnt_draw(green.size(), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
Scalar green_cnt_colors[3];
green_cnt_colors[0] = Scalar(0, 255, 0);
green_cnt_colors[1] = Scalar(0, 255, 0);
green_cnt_colors[2] = Scalar(0, 255, 0);

for (size_t idx_green = 0; idx_green < green_cnt.size(); idx_green++){
    drawContours(green_cnt_draw, green_cnt, idx_green, green_cnt_colors[idx_green % 3]);
}

namedWindow("Green - Contours", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Green - Contours", green_cnt_draw);
waitKey(0);

//Yellow Contour
findContours(yellow, yellow_cnt, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

//Draw the Contours - Yellow
Mat yellow_cnt_draw(yellow.size(), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
Scalar yellow_cnt_colors[3];
yellow_cnt_colors[0] = Scalar(0, 255, 255);
yellow_cnt_colors[1] = Scalar(0, 255, 255);
yellow_cnt_colors[2] = Scalar(0, 255, 255);

for (size_t idx_yellow = 0; idx_yellow < yellow_cnt.size(); idx_yellow++){
    drawContours(yellow_cnt_draw, yellow_cnt, idx_yellow, yellow_cnt_colors[idx_yellow % 3]);
}

namedWindow("Yellow - Contours", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Yellow - Contours", yellow_cnt_draw);
waitKey(0);

//Brown Contour
findContours(brown, brown_cnt, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

//Draw the Contours - Brown
Mat brown_cnt_draw(brown.size(), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
Scalar brown_cnt_colors[3];
brown_cnt_colors[0] = Scalar(42, 42, 165);
brown_cnt_colors[1] = Scalar(42, 42, 165);
brown_cnt_colors[1] = Scalar(42, 42, 165);

for (size_t idx_brown = 0; idx_brown < brown_cnt.size(); idx_brown++){
    drawContours(brown_cnt_draw, brown_cnt, idx_brown, brown_cnt_colors[idx_brown % 3]);
}

namedWindow("Brown - Contours", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Brown - Contours", brown_cnt_draw);
waitKey(0);
destroyAllWindows;

// logical OR mask
Mat1b mask = yellow | green | brown;

// Find non zero pixels
vector<Point> pts;

findNonZero(mask, pts);

// Compute ellipse
RotatedRect elipse = fitEllipse(pts);

//ELLIPSE - Heigth, Width and Center of Mass
cout << "ELLIPSE:" << endl;
cout << "\nHeight and Width: " << elipse.size;  //Height and Width
cout << "\nCenter of Mass: " << elipse.center << endl;  //Center of mass (probably given in X and Y coordinates)

// Show Ellipse
ellipse(img_bgr, elipse, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
namedWindow("Ellipse", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Ellipse", img_bgr); 

waitKey(0);
destroyAllWindows;

return 0;
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

In response to the question made by the user, i've decided to edit the main post instead of simply reply without new images to illustrate the situation.

The mask after the findCountours() looks like this:
[image]

And without it:
[image]

With our without the contours, the final result is always the same.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Following the solution given by the user **sietschie**, I tried to implement his code, which is available [here](http://pastebin.com/XikhXTW9), but it turns out that I always get an error at the line 105. The message shown at the command line is:

***OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (Number of points should be >= 5) in cvFitEllipse2, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src.cpp, line 799***

I still cannot figure out what I did wrong, since this is the same come he wrote and worked, as he showed the result.
In order to try to understand what is happening, I got the image of the contour (line 104) and it actually looks pretty weird:

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at what the 4 Mats look like after this line: `Mat1b mask = yellow | green | brown;`? **findContours(...)** modifies the input image in an undefined way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you try to fit the ellipse using all the white pixels of the mask. This results in an ellipse that tries to minimise the distance to all the white pixels. What you want is an ellipse that minimises the distance to the contour of the mask. Like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::Mat tmp = mask.clone();
cv::findContours(tmp, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
cv::RotatedRect elipse = cv::fitEllipse(contours[0]);
```

This results in a much better approximation apart from the region where the stem is located.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution but the code is not compiling. Visual Studio is showing an error with the code 0x000007FEFD7A965D. Have you changed any other part of the code or just added this part to get the result shown above?To be more precise, the error occurs in the last line.

Comment: That is all I added. Just to be sure, [here](http://pastebin.com/XikhXTW9) is the whole file I used. I commented out some things here and there. But nothing that should influence the way it works.

Comment: I tried to run your code from the link you posted but it is not compiling yet.

I noticed the following message at the command line:

OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (Number of points should be >= 5) in cvFitEllipse2, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src.cpp, line 799

Do you have any idea of how to solve this problem?

What version of OpenCV are you using? Mine is 2.4.10.

The only difference between our codes is that I'm using a path to an especific image instead of passing the path manually using the command line.

Comment: I am using 2.4.12. Check how your `mask` looks like and what the contour looks like that is used to fit the ellipse. The error message suggests you end up with a contour with less than 5 points.

Comment: I edited the main question with the information that we were discussing here to make it easier for people to understand the current situation.
I also posted the results of the mask and the contour as you suggested.

Comment: The last image you posted. Is that `mask` or `tmp`? That is how `tmp` looks like, after you ran `findContours()` because it modifies the input image. If `mask` already looks like this, the input to `findContours()` is wrong. Also when I run it `contours.size()` equals 1 and `contours[0].size()` is 5820.

Comment: The last image is the "temp". I'm sorry, but i didn't understand the last sentence. Could you please explain it with more details?

Comment: I can't understand why I'm getting this error and why i can't compile the same code that you wrote and worked.
What can possibly be wrong if I'm just copying and pasting?

Comment: sietschie - I have changed my library version to 2.4.12 like yours and the code shows the same error. Please, could explain why your code doesn't work if we have the same development enviornment?